# How to display the current time from a specific Timezone in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, time, timezone

I have created a JSON file to list the maximum number of country codes for each region in the world, and then based on the user's system language, I retrieve the global time zone of the region and store it in a String

From this String, I would like to display the current time of the time zone, but I am unable to do so. I have tried using package, but I am encountering errors

I tried the [timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) plugin, I followed the documentation but I get this error :

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Isolate.resolvePackageUri
#0      initializeTimeZone.<anonymous closure> (package:timezone/standalone.dart:81:5)
#1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1660:54)
#2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:165:22)
#3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
#5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:575:5)
#6      Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:666:7)
#7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#8      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

For an example here is my current code :

```
void _getDateTime(String countryZone) async {
  await tz.initializeTimeZone();

  var timezone = tz.getLocation(countryZone);
  var now = tz.TZDateTime.now(timezone);

  currentTime = formatTime(now);
}

String formatTime(tz.TZDateTime time) {
  var formatter = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss');
  var formattedTime = formatter.format(time.toLocal());

  return formattedTime;
}
```

My main function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  //...
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Apart from this one I have not found any other package that can define a timezone from a String, **do you have a solution to my problem?**

*By the way if you also have a solution to retrieve the day of the year based on the same string explained above I'm interested*

Comment: what are you passing around as the countryZone value ?

Comment: Is countryZone something like 'America/LosAngeles' ?

Comment: @arma  Did u find any solution?? me also getting the same error..

Comment: @KJEjava48 Apologies for the delayed response. Yes, I've found a solution. You can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/easy_timezone. The line of code that we're interested in is format with `now.toTimeZone()`